# SQL reduce work done in SELECT when only one row is needed for each foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Below is an example of the data I have where ID is a foreign key in another table (this table is called test).

```
+------+------+
| id   | data |
+------+------+
|    1 |  100 |
|    1 |  110 |
|    1 |  105 |
|    2 |  105 |
|    2 |  150 |
|    2 |  120 |
|    2 |  320 |
|    3 |  300 |
|    3 |  400 |
|    3 |  500 |
+------+------+
```

The SELECT statement I have run (which gives me the result I am looking for) is:

```
select distinct(id) from test where data < 160 and data > 130;
```

This query returns the foreign key if it matches the criteria in the WHERE clause. This gives me a unique list of foreign keys I can use later.

From my understanding using distinct in this situation doesn't reduce the work done, it only filters the full result set of any duplicates. This means although we have a unique foreign key matched at row:

```
|    2 |  150 |
```

The remaining rows are still checked.

Is it possible to make a query which will first check if a match has already been found for a particular foreign key, and if it hasn't only then test the data column with the WHERE clause.

Comment: Please decide on the database you are using:  Oracle or MySQL.

Comment: `distinct()` is not a function, really. while `select distinct(id)` is "proper" syntax, `distinct` as a keyword applies to the ENTIRE row of fields, not just whatever fields you listed in the `()`. but  otherwise, yes. the `where` filter is applied, then all previously found rows are examined to check if the current row would be a dupe of any of those previous rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff A solution in either would be fine. Hence both tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `select distinct` is doing an aggregation.  Aggregations can be cumbersome operations, depending on the database.

If performance is a consideration, you might consider a query such as:

```
select rt.id
from referencetable rt
where exists (select 1 from test t2 where t2.id = rt.id and t2.data < 160 and t2.data > 130);
```

`referencetable` is the table where `id` is the primary key.

The advantage to this query is that it will read the reference table and then look up the values (presumably in a index on `(id, data)`) in `test`.  There is no duplicate elimination, so under many circumstances, this might be the faster approach.  Not always, but often.